# Comparing two dataframes based off one column, with the equal values in different index positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I am having an issue trying to find a solution to a problem I seem to be coming across.

I am trying to compare two dataframes which are quite large, but for the case of my first issue, I have reduced this to a smaller sample size.

At the present time, I would like to simply print out the name of a player that is in both of these dataframes. In the future I will be then looping through the columns to compare the values and record the difference, but that is future me problems.

I have noticed that in other examples and solutions being shared, most people will have the two values that they want to compare, in the same index, however I am not experienced enough with Pandas commands to know how to manipulate these solutions.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel('Example players 2019.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('Example players 2018.xlsx')

header2019 = df1.iloc[0] 
df1 = df1[1:] 
df1.columns = header2019
header2018 = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2[1:]
df2.columns = header2018

print('df1')
print(df1)
print('df2')
print(df2)

columnLength2019=df1.shape[1]
columnLength2018=df2.shape[1]

rowLength2019=df1.shape[0]
rowLength2018=df2.shape[0]

for i in range (1, rowLength2019):
    for j in range (1, rowLength2018):
        if df1['Player'] == df2['Player']:
            print(df1['Player'])
```

[Example players 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4cu7.png)
[Example players 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vk3p.png)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to merge the two dataframes on the player column, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_2018 = pd.DataFrame({'player':['a','b','c'], 'team':['x','y','z']})
df_2019 = pd.DataFrame({'player':['b','c','d'], 'team':['y','j','k']})

matched = df_2018.merge(df_2019,
                        on='player',
                        how='inner',
                        suffixes=['_2018','_2019']
                        )
print(matched)
```

Output:

```
  player team_2018 team_2019
0      b         y         y
1      c         z         j
```

To print out the matching players you can then do something like:

```
for player in matched['player']:
    print(player)
```

Having both years of data in the same DataFrame should also make it easier to compare them later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` to chek if a value is in a series

```
a =df1[(df1.player.isin(df2.player))]
for player in a['player']:
    print(player)
```

Or you can use `np.where` with `isin` to chekc & print in a single line.

```
np.where((df1.player.isin(df2.player)), df1.player+ " is present", df1.player+ " is NOT present").tolist()
```

You use `np.where` to create a column in your dataframe as well

```
df1['present'] = np.where((df1.player.isin(df2.player)), "Present", "NOT present")
```